# Spring security session not working when Angular app is running in development (ng serve)

Tags: angular, spring-security

As the title implies, I have the backend developed using Spring/Spring Security and the frontend is an Angular app.

When I launch angular app using ng serve (http://localhost:4200), spring session is not working.
When I request the application to be served from the backend (http://localhost:8080), the spring session is working as expected.

**Most relevant spring security configs**

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .httpBasic()
        .and()
        .logout().clearAuthentication(true).invalidateHttpSession(true).deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
        .and()
        .rememberMe().key("uniqueAndSecret").rememberMeParameter("rememberMe").tokenValiditySeconds(Integer.parseInt(rememberMeDuration))
        .and()
        .authorizeHttpRequests().antMatchers(UNPROTECTED_ROUTES).permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .csrf().disable()
        .cors().configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource())
        .and()
        .authenticationManager(authManager(http, userDetailsServiceConfig))
        .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.ALWAYS);
    return http.build();
}

@Bean
CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();

    configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
    configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList(HttpMethod.GET.name(), HttpMethod.HEAD.name(), HttpMethod.POST.name(), HttpMethod.OPTIONS.name()));
    configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Collections.singletonList("*"));
    configuration.setExposedHeaders(Collections.singletonList("*"));
    configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Collections.singletonList("http://localhost:4200"));

    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration(
            "/**",
            new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues().combine( configuration)
    );
    return source;
}
```

**And an example of a request from the frontend that does not work (when running from ng serve). I get always 401 (when I call this code I already did a successful authentication)**

```
public vehicleAlimentationByCSV(formData: FormData): Observable<VehicleAlimentationResponseModel> {
    const endPoint = `${this.url}/csv`;

    return this.http
        .post<VehicleAlimentationResponseModel>(
            endPoint,
            formData,
            {
                observe: 'response',
                withCredentials: true
            }
        )
        .pipe(
            map(resp => resp.body!)
        );
}
```

Maybe a very simple miss configuration. I have searched for an explanation why this is happening but I got nothing.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I little bit late, but better late than never...

When running on port 4200, in development mode, in order for the cookie JSESSIONID   work properly we just need to add 'withCredential: true' to the request options:

```
public login(email: string, password: string, rememberMe: boolean): Observable<UserModel> {
    let basicAuth = btoa(`${email}:${password}`);

    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
        'Authorization': `Basic ${basicAuth}`
    });

    this.loadingService.startLoading();

    return this.http
        .post<UserModel>(`${this.domainUrl}login?rememberMe=${rememberMe}`, {}, {headers: headers, observe: 'response', withCredentials: true})
        .pipe(
            map(resp => new UserModel(resp.body!.email, resp.body!.role)),
            tap(user => {
                this.user.next(user);
                this.loadingService.stopLoading();
            }),
            catchError(err => {
                this.loadingService.stopLoading();
                throw err;
            })
        );
}
```